# WSO2 add assertions in SAML request

Tags: wso2, saml, wso2-identity-server

Does any one know, how to add additional assertions in a SAML request to federated iDP? The problem is that there is no nameID in SAML request:

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<samlp:AuthnRequest AssertionConsumerServiceURL="https://testserver.domain.local:9443/commonauth"
                    Destination="https://idp.eu.safenetid.com/auth/realms/XXXXXXXXXX-STA/protocol/saml"
                    ForceAuthn="true"
                    ID="_b53cdb3765c8b92fa51d6079a061deaf"
                    IsPassive="false"
                    IssueInstant="2021-02-03T10:45:48.275Z"
                    ProtocolBinding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST"
                    Version="2.0"
                    xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol">
  <samlp:Issuer xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">WSO2</samlp:Issuer>
  <saml2p:RequestedAuthnContext Comparison="exact"
                                xmlns:saml2p="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol">
    <saml2:AuthnContextClassRef xmlns:saml2="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:unspecified</saml2:AuthnContextClassRef>
  </saml2p:RequestedAuthnContext>
</samlp:AuthnRequest>
```

We configured federated iDP - SafeNet and wont to use it as second factor auth.
I configured 2 steps in SP where first step is basic auth and second step is federeted iDP - SafeNet (Saml2webSSO). But, as you can see WSO2 do not include nameID in request and username do not populated on safenet login page. May be we can, some how, configure what to include in SAML request?

Answer (score 0):

You can enable NameID Policy in the authentication request by enabling the ***Include NameID Policy*** configuration in your IDP configuration. (Identity Provider > Federated Authenticators>  SAML2 Web SSO Configuration )

[image]

You can add the requested NameID policy as well in the **NameID format** config.

[image]

Comment: Yes, you a right, i can enable Name ID Policy, but this does not help it's just add nameidpolicy in SAML request. there is still no nameID attribute.

Comment: For username to be populated on safenet logon page, safenet should receive SAML request with nameID from WSO2. nameID may contain user emal for example that's will be enough for safenet

Comment: I mean SAML request from WSO2 should contain this 
 <saml:NameID Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress">user.name@myorg.com</saml:NameID>

Comment: Since IS sends an authentication request to the federated IDP, the request will not have an nameID attribute. NameID attribute can be found in the authentication response from an IDP. In your scennario, since safenet acts as an IDP and WSO2IS acts as a relying party, IS will send an authetication request to the federated IDP